# How can we communicate with 3 same USB devices with a single USB interface?

Tags: c#, embedded, usb, driver

Actually we have a USB Scanner device for which we have written a USB core in C++ and its application in c#. Its VID and PID is specific and we communicate based on its PID and VID. Its API is singleton right now.

In fact we have one idea to connect with scanner with VID and PID and later on change its PID in order to connect with second scanner and then change its PID also to connect third one. In this regard how we have to change its USB core only to accommodate these three scanner all at once and as we want to keep the top layer singleton so UI is also one but provide connectivity for three scanners.

Any other idea is also appreciated that how should we change the already singleton API so that now it accommodate more than one scanner at once?

Comment: You cannot change PID or VID, that breaks plug & play.  Pretty unclear why you think you need this, the OS already assigns a unique device name for each device when it connects.

Comment: what if all devices are same vendor same product connected? should they be also having different unique device names?? the thing is we want to operate many scanners at once but the API we have design before only work for a unique instance? how we can convert it easily so that it may now control 2 or more scanners at once??

Comment: By the way how should i get the unique device name for all scanners connected?? any suggestion for what package and what command can do that?? Thanks in advance